# Java equivalent of PHP array POST data

Tags: java, php, tomcat, http-post

In PHP I can do the following

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" value="val1" />
<input type="text" name="title[]" value="val2" />
```

What is the equivalent of `name="title[]"` in Java ?

or what can me and my team do to do the same thing ?

Comment: Do you some more information on the type of the array? Of course you can for example `String[] name = new String[LENGTH]`;

Comment: Your question is unclear! Do you want to know how specify an array of parameters on the **client** side (HTML form), or do you want to know how to **process** values from a request sent from a form with such an array (server side)?

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to make html as code

Comment: I think this helped me `request.getParameterValues("cat[]")` I am not sure if this is the correct way or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't pay attention to `[]` as a special chars. You can get parameters with the following snippet:

```
public static Map<String, String> getParameterMap(ServletRequest request, String mapName) {

  Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();     

  Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames();
  while (names.hasMoreElements()) { 
    String name = names.getNextElement();
    if (name.startsWith(mapName + "[") && name.endsWith("]")) {
      result.put(name.substring(mapName.length()+1, name.length() - 2), request.getParameter(name));
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```